# Create Custom JSON using GSON and Hibernate Entity

Tags: java, json, hibernate, jax-rs, gson

I have the following Hibernate entity:

```
@Entity
public class DesignActivity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Expose
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;


    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private int version;

    @Expose
    @NotEmpty
    @NotNull
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "designActivity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Cost> costs = new HashSet<Cost>();

// getter and setter
}
```

And also the following GSON code to return the entity in JSON form via JAX-RS:

```
BaseDesign baseDesign = em.find(BaseDesign.class, id);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
return Response.ok(gson.toJson(baseDesign)).build();
```

And the following returned JSON:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Sew Collar",
    "costs":[
        {
             "value":"1.05"
        },
        {
             "value":"1.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

In the above JSON, it returned an array of costs, but what I need, is to return only the first 'cost', like this:

```
{
    "id":1,
    "name":"Sew Collar",
    "cost":{
             "value":"1.05"
           },
}
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have following suggestion:

1) Please create following custom `JsonSerializer` to exclude `costs` and include `cost`:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializationContext;
import com.google.gson.JsonSerializer;

public class CustomSerializer implements JsonSerializer<BaseDesign> {
@Override
public JsonElement serialize(BaseDesign src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
    JsonObject object = new JsonObject();
    object.addProperty("id", src.getId());
    object.addProperty("name", src.getName());
    List<Cost> listOfCost = src.getCosts();
    if (listOfCost != null && listOfCost.size() != 0) {
        object.addProperty("cost", listOfCost.get(0).getValue());
        object.remove("costs");
    }
    return object;
  }

}
```

2) Create your `gson` object in following manner:

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(BaseDesign.class, new CustomSerializer())
                .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
                .create();`

Comment: Hi @sanjeev Saha, this strategy will have a redundant 'cost' field which need to be updated every time when 'costs' changed. If I am going to have both 'cost' and 'costs' in the same entity, I would already use Expose annotation to 'costs' instead of ExclusionStrategy. Thanks.

Comment: Hello @VHanded, I have edited my solution. Please see whether it works for you or not. You do not have to add a redundant `cost` field in `BaseDesign` class.

Comment: I haven't test it, but it seems correct, I just found out about JsonSerializer too.